# F# script cannot find type in referenced assembly

Tags: c#, f#, f#-interactive, idataerrorinfo, system.componentmodel

I'm using Core 3.1 to build a C# WPF MVVM application. I have a base view model class that implements IDataErrorInfo and works fine. This uses a reference to System.ComponentModel.

I'm using F# to test the view models and am trying to use an F# script to write a helper function that uses my view model to make testing easier. I've referenced the relevant assemblies and opened them, and the script doesn't show any errors on screen (no red squigglies).

```
#r "bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/TrialModellerGui.dll"
#r "System.ObjectModel"
#r "System.ComponentModel.dll"

open System
open TrialModellerGui.ViewModels.Helpers
open System.ComponentModel

let a = MainViewModelBase()
```

However, when running the script I receive the error

```
error FS0193: The module/namespace 'System.ComponentModel' from compilation unit 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter' did not contain the namespace, module or type 'IDataErrorInfo'



Script1.fsx(16,9): error FS1109: A reference to the type 'System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo' in assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter' was found, but the type could not be found in that assembly
```

IDataErrorInfo is in the System.ComponentModel namespaces so I've no idea why this is giving this error. Anyone?